# Coloring a 3-player Chess board with 3 colors

Tags: permutations, coloring

I'm referring to this type of chess:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-Man_Chess

It has $96$ "squares".

If $32$ of the "squares" are black, $32$ are white and $32$ are red, is it possible to arrange them such that no two squares which share a side/edge have the same color?

Comment: Hi Jose, i think it is possible to brute force the answer, though Im not sure what software to use

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do it (I apologize in advance for using flood-fill in MSPaint):

[image]

In each color, there are two symmetrically-arranged "pieces" of $16$ squares joined at their corners. This setup also has the aesthetically pleasing property that nobody's starting squares share a color with their pieces.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7brv.png) is another such coloring found by a completely different approach. Here, we start with a checkerboard coloring with $48$ black and $48$ white squares, and change $16$ of each color to red. I've tried to do this somewhat symmetrically, but there are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: No worries, it looks great! Thanks Misha

Comment: do you think this could be the only solution?

Comment: Far from it. There's plenty of room to tweak this solution: any of the squares surrounded by only one color can be recolored. There's probably a large number of solutions that don't look anything like this one, too.

Comment: yup, that's what I meant, that all solutions are of similar arrangement to the one you've made.

Comment: @ Misha this type of board is being made and sold, but so far, I haven't found any 3 color version. Your coloring could possibly be the first one.   :)

Comment: It may well be the first time someone considered the problem, but that doesn't mean there's few possible solutions. I've just added on a solution by a different approach, where the color red is treated differently from the others, and which should also have many variants.